# Counter going above abviable stock and below initial values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am burning out here so I may be missing something, why is it not following the parameters?

```
const addItem = () => {
    const newValue = setCounter(counter +1);
       
    if (newValue < {stock}){
        setCounter(newValue)
    } else if (newValue > {stock}) {
        alert("Stock is full");
        setCounter({stock})
    }
}

const quitItem = () => {
    const newValue = setCounter(counter -1)
    if (newValue < initial){
        setCounter(initial)
    }

}
```

Comment: If this fixed your problem @ElPuli, please remember to set my answer as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you call setCounter, you are actually updating its value in React state. So in the first line inside `addItem` you have already updated the value of the counter.

The next thing is that you inside `addItem` is comparing `newValue` to an object with the variable `stock`. You should probably compare the value against the value of `stock`, not an object containing `stock`.

Try this:

```
const addItem = () => {
    const newValue = counter + 1;
       
    if (newValue < stock){
        setCounter(newValue)
    } else if (newValue > stock) {
        alert("Stock is full");
        setCounter(stock)
    }
}

const quitItem = () => {
    const newValue = counter -1
    if (newValue < initial){
        setCounter(initial)
    }

}
```